# How to connect the normal equation to the Gram-Schmidt method of finding an orthogonal vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection, gram-schmidt

From [this lecture](https://youtu.be/uNsCkP9mgRk?t=1281), if given $Q$ a matrix where each column is orthogonal to each other, and $b$ which is some vector we want to project onto the column space of $Q$, the projection matrix is given by $QQ^T$ (as from the normal equations $Qx = b \to Qx=Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^Tb= QQ^Tb$) so the vector orthogonal to the column space of $Q$ is $b – QQ^Tb$.

On page 3 of [these notes](https://www.math.utk.edu/~mengesha/teaching/Math2025/Lecture8.pdf), given some $v$ and an orthogonal basis $v_1, v_2,…v_n$ for some vector space $W$, the author uses Gram-Schmidt to find that $v-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{<v,v_j>}{||v_j||^2}v_j$ is orthogonal to $W$.

If I define the columns of $Q$ to contain the orthogonal basis $[v_1 v_2 .... v_n]$, do the two methods give the same result? If so, is there a way to use the first method to arrive at the equation for the second?

Comment: Yes, they would give the same result. Can you elaborate what you mean by "using the first method to arrive at the equation for the second"?

Comment: @paulinho To clarify: my question is basically, is there a way to manipulate $v-QQ^Tv$ to $v-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{<v,v_j>}{||v_j||^2}v_j$ if $Q=[v_1 v_2 .... v_n]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having trouble showing the equivalence because you need additional assumptions for the projection matrix to be $QQ^T$ in the first place: it’s actually $Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$. With the additional assumption that the columns of $Q$ are unit vectors, this reduces to $QQ^T$. If we remove this restriction, however, we’re no longer guaranteed that $Q^TQ$ is invertible: we need to add the condition that the columns of $Q$ are linearly independent. (Pairwise orthogonality of the columns isn’t enough since the zero vector is orthogonal to everything.) Equivalently, $Q$ must have full column rank.

Setting $Q=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_n\end{bmatrix}$, we have by orthogonality of the columns $$Q^TQ = \begin{bmatrix}\langle v_1,v_1\rangle&0&\cdots&0\\0&\langle v_2,v_2\rangle&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&\langle v_n,v_n\rangle\end{bmatrix}$$ with all of the diagonal entries nonzero. We can then expand directly: $$Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^Tb = Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\langle v_1,b\rangle \\ \langle v_2,b\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle v_n,b\rangle\end{bmatrix} = Q\begin{bmatrix}{\langle v_1,b\rangle \over \langle v_1,v_1\rangle} \\ {\langle v_2,b\rangle \over \langle v_2,v_2\rangle} \\ \vdots \\ {\langle v_n,b\rangle \over \langle v_n,v_n\rangle} \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{j=1}^n {\langle v_j,b\rangle \over \langle v_j,v_j\rangle} v_j.$$

Comment: To clarify on the assumptions, if $v_1, v_2,...v_n$ are unit vectors then that alone is sufficient and $Q^TQ = I$, otherwise $v_1, v_2,...v_n$ must be orthogonal and non-zero (which is equivalent to saying they're linearly independent), and $Q^T$ is not the inverse of $Q$?

Comment: @Yandle Remember that $Q$ might not be square, in which case you have to consider its left and right inverses separately. If the $v_i$ are pairwise orthogonal, then $Q^TQ$ will be diagonal, but not necessarily the identity. Note, too, that for the projection matrix to be $Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$, all that’s required is full column rank, but in the general case you won’t be able to decompose it into a sum of rank-one orthogonal projections as we can here. Finally, orthogonal and non-zero implies linear independence, but not the other way around, so I wouldn’t say that they’re equivalent.

Comment: Is $Q^TQ = I$ for any $Q$ as long as the columns are unit vectors (which implies non-zero) and pairwise orthogonal, and if this is the case we should be able to decompose it into sum of rank-one orthogonal projections as above? If $Q$ is simply full column rank, $Q^TQ$ may not be diagonal which might make it impossible to simplify?

Does linear independent imply that vectors are non-zero, not necessarily orthogonal?